# Adjacency list creation in Python

Tags: python, adjacency-list

I'm trying to implement an adjacency list by using the text file which includes:

```
0,1,5,1,3,1,0,3,1,1,0,4,7,1,0,4,0,4,1,6,5,1,1,3,6,3,4,1,5,2
6,0,1,4,1,5,3,0,4,5,1,4,7,4,2,0,3,5,4,1,3,1,7,3,2,1,1,6,5,0
4,6,0,3,1,6,1,6,2,1,2,2,7,7,7,1,1,1,6,1,1,5,1,6,1,6,1,2,5,3
6,4,5,0,4,1,6,1,6,2,1,0,6,5,1,3,0,1,0,7,5,1,6,6,3,2,3,1,6,4
4,2,0,6,0,0,4,6,3,3,3,6,7,0,1,4,5,7,3,4,2,3,7,7,1,4,6,6,4,5
0,2,6,1,6,0,3,3,6,1,4,4,3,5,0,7,3,7,3,7,0,2,7,1,7,2,5,7,1,0
7,4,5,2,2,2,0,3,1,4,0,6,0,3,7,1,4,6,6,6,6,1,1,6,1,3,3,3,2,0
2,0,1,3,1,7,2,0,3,0,5,2,3,4,1,7,1,0,1,5,3,6,1,2,2,0,5,2,4,0
7,3,2,6,2,6,6,1,0,1,0,6,2,3,0,5,2,1,7,0,0,3,3,0,1,1,1,4,6,1
4,1,7,4,2,5,7,1,4,0,4,3,6,1,6,6,1,0,4,0,0,0,2,2,4,2,6,0,7,5
1,1,2,1,0,5,1,6,2,6,0,4,4,6,2,5,1,1,0,0,5,0,1,1,2,5,1,3,6,6
0,3,7,3,1,4,6,1,2,7,1,0,4,4,1,1,6,7,1,5,0,4,0,4,6,3,1,4,1,0
1,4,7,0,4,1,5,3,1,0,0,6,0,0,5,0,3,5,4,7,2,1,4,7,3,1,5,7,3,2
3,1,5,3,3,4,2,4,4,5,1,7,6,0,3,3,0,0,7,7,3,5,6,7,0,2,1,0,2,2
3,1,4,4,1,5,1,5,6,2,6,4,5,7,0,0,4,1,3,7,5,1,0,4,5,4,5,1,1,0
```

Think of every line has the index number as the name instead of A,B,C.... So for example `0,1,5,1,3,1,0,3,1,1,0,4,7,1,0,4,0,4,1,6,5,1,1,3,6,3,4,1,5,2` is the node `0` and `6,0,1,4,1,5,3,0,4,5,1,4,7,4,2,0,3,5,4,1,3,1,7,3,2,1,1,6,5,0` is the node `1` etc. The problem here is I cannot extract elements because of the "," between each element. I tried this:

```
a = np.array([])
with open("routers.txt") as f:
    adj_list = list(f)
    node_no = 0
    node_list = list()

    for i in adj_list:

        node_list.append(node_no)
        if i[node_no] != ",":
          a = np.append(a, i[node_no])
          node_no += 1
        elif i[node_no] == ",":
          break
```

But it cannot go further, when it sees "," it stops.

Comment: Use the split method to split each line on the commas, e.g `line.split(',')`

Comment: So your file contains name of the nodes only? Where is the adjacency here? I.E. where the edges are stored?

Comment: i.split(",") will give you a list of the values in each line without the commas

Comment: i couldn't go further than extracting the data here yet, but there will be lists for them @aminrd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary and store the node/index as key and the line as a value:

```
file = open("file.txt")
raw_f = file.readlines()
d = {}
for line in raw_f:
    d|= {raw_f.index(line):line}

    
print(d)
```

for example:
`print(d[0])`
will give you the first line as output:

```
 0,1,5,1,3,1,0,3,1,1,0,4,7,1,0,4,0,4,1,6,5,1,1,3,6,3,4,1,5,2
```

if you want to stay with a list use:

```
file = open("KontoN.txt")
raw_f = file.readlines()
res = []

for line in raw_f:
    res.append(line)

    
print(res)
```

then:

```
print(res[0])
```

will give you:

```
0,1,5,1,3,1,0,3,1,1,0,4,7,1,0,4,0,4,1,6,5,1,1,3,6,3,4,1,5,2
```

for removing the `,` between the numbers you can use replace for example:

```
d|= {raw_f.index(line):line.replace(",","")}
```

or for 2nd case:

```
res.append(line.replace(",",""))
```

for the output in both cases `d[0]` and `res[0]` to be:

```
015131031104710404165113634152
```

I recommend using dictionaries, because the lookup time is faster than the lookup time in lists.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, explanations and time! it really helped me a lot and saved me! :)

Comment: im glad that i was able to help you, you are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use split:

```
text = """0,1,5,1,3,1,0,3,1,1,0,4,7,1,0,4,0,4,1,6,5,1,1,3,6,3,4,1,5,2
6,0,1,4,1,5,3,0,4,5,1,4,7,4,2,0,3,5,4,1,3,1,7,3,2,1,1,6,5,0
4,6,0,3,1,6,1,6,2,1,2,2,7,7,7,1,1,1,6,1,1,5,1,6,1,6,1,2,5,3
6,4,5,0,4,1,6,1,6,2,1,0,6,5,1,3,0,1,0,7,5,1,6,6,3,2,3,1,6,4
4,2,0,6,0,0,4,6,3,3,3,6,7,0,1,4,5,7,3,4,2,3,7,7,1,4,6,6,4,5
0,2,6,1,6,0,3,3,6,1,4,4,3,5,0,7,3,7,3,7,0,2,7,1,7,2,5,7,1,0
7,4,5,2,2,2,0,3,1,4,0,6,0,3,7,1,4,6,6,6,6,1,1,6,1,3,3,3,2,0
2,0,1,3,1,7,2,0,3,0,5,2,3,4,1,7,1,0,1,5,3,6,1,2,2,0,5,2,4,0
7,3,2,6,2,6,6,1,0,1,0,6,2,3,0,5,2,1,7,0,0,3,3,0,1,1,1,4,6,1
4,1,7,4,2,5,7,1,4,0,4,3,6,1,6,6,1,0,4,0,0,0,2,2,4,2,6,0,7,5
1,1,2,1,0,5,1,6,2,6,0,4,4,6,2,5,1,1,0,0,5,0,1,1,2,5,1,3,6,6
0,3,7,3,1,4,6,1,2,7,1,0,4,4,1,1,6,7,1,5,0,4,0,4,6,3,1,4,1,0
1,4,7,0,4,1,5,3,1,0,0,6,0,0,5,0,3,5,4,7,2,1,4,7,3,1,5,7,3,2
3,1,5,3,3,4,2,4,4,5,1,7,6,0,3,3,0,0,7,7,3,5,6,7,0,2,1,0,2,2
3,1,4,4,1,5,1,5,6,2,6,4,5,7,0,0,4,1,3,7,5,1,0,4,5,4,5,1,1,0"""

lst = text.split('\n')

dct = dict()
for i, line in enumerate(lst):
    dct[i] = line.split(',')

print(dct[0])
#['0', '1', '5', '1', '3', '1', '0', '3', '1', '1', '0', '4', '7', '1', '0', '4', '0', '4', '1', '6', '5', '1', '1', '3', '6', '3', '4', '1', '5', '2']
```

---

Or in one line:

```
dct = {i: l.split(',') for i, l in enumerate(text.split('\n'))}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to read lines of a file into an array.

You can do this with `str.split()`.

In your case:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    a.append([int(i) for i in line.split(',')])
```